# Set the default settings value during run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, settings, settings.settings

I use the Properties.Settings.Default to save the user settings of my program. This includes the size and position of the Main Window. See the
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A35bu.png) here. These represent the default values asigned when I call

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
```

When I call

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Height = 25;
```

for example, the user setting gets saved as 25 by calling

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

When I now go for reset() and save(), the default value I chose in the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A35bu.png) are again given back when calling

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Height;
```

How can I change these default values **during runtime** so that when I call reset(), my newly assigned values are being taken? (Even when I close the program and reopen again. It should consequently update in the Picture as well)

Comment: I feel as though you may be using default values improperly. Default values usually should not change at runtime as they would no longer be default - but rather, dynamic.

Comment: Am I able to set dynamic default values, for example the size of the users screen? @ChrisCruz

Comment: _"How can I change these default values during runtime so that when I call reset(), my newly assigned values are being taken?"_ -- I don't understand your question. What is the point of the `Reset()` method, if you want it to _not_ reset the values? And if you want to _not_ reset the values, wouldn't it be better to just not call `Reset()` instead of trying to change the default values to whatever is currently set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523619/how-can-i-set-application-settings-at-install-time-via-installer-class

Answer (score 2):

Changing Settings.Default shouldn't be a problem if parameters scope set to User. Parameters in Application scope are read-only. Here is my setup.

[Settings.Default example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJrdP.png)

Then I use it in public field for two way binding like so.

```
public double CurrRateRubToUSD
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Settings.Default.CurrencyRateRubToUSD;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != Properties.Settings.Default.CurrencyRateRubToUSD)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.CurrencyRateRubToUSD = value;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
            }
        }
    }
```